# Datos no se visualizan en el ListView pero si se ve que se esta llena

Tags: android

```
public class FillList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String z = "";
        ListView lstpoints = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstpoints);
        List<Map<String, String>> pointslist  = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

            pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(MapsPreviosProductor.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String[] from = { "_id", "Latitud", "Longitud"};
            int[] views = { R.id.lblidpunprepro, R.id.lbllatprepro, R.id.lbllonprepro};
            final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(MapsPreviosProductor.this,  pointslist, R.layout.lstpunpreproii, from,  views);

            lstpoints.setAdapter(ADA);

            lstpoints.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) ADA.getItem(arg2);
                    idpoint = (String) obj.get("A");
                    String latitud = (String) obj.get("B");
                    String longitud = (String) obj.get("C");
                    txtlatitud.setText(latitud);
                    txtlongitud.setText(longitud);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("SAICoffeeSQL", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                if (db == null) {
                    z = "Error al conectar con la base de datos";
                } else {
                    String query = "select _id, Latitud, Longitud from TB_previos_productor";
                    Cursor ps = db.rawQuery(query, null);
                    //ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ps.moveToFirst();
                    while (ps.moveToNext()){
                       Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                       datanum.put("A", ps.getString(ps.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                       datanum.put("B", ps.getString(ps.getColumnIndex("Latitud")));
                       datanum.put("C", ps.getString(ps.getColumnIndex("Longitud")));
                      pointslist.add(datanum);
                   }
                    z = "Consulta exitosa";
                    db.close();
                    ps.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                z = "Error al obtener los valores de las tabla";
            }
            return z;
        }
    }
```

Comment: El titulo de una pregunta debe ser corto y conciso. En el contenido de la pregunta planteas claramente tu problema. Corrige tu pregunta por favor.

Comment: Parece una bobada pero prueba a poner el background del layout de un color que no sea blanco. A mi me ocurrió algo parecido

Comment: gracias por las recomendaciones soy nuevo, tratare de ser mas especifico con lo que pregunto....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque lo comentas, asegura que la lista "views" en realidad tenga valores, si es así también te hace falta llamar al método `notifyDataSetChanged()`; de tu Adapter:

```
 listview.setAdapter(adapter);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

De acuerdo a tu código dentro de `onPostExecute()` de tu `Asynctask` sería:

```
 lstpoints.setAdapter(ADA);
 ADA.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

- Otro caso que comenta @KubaHc es, cuando esta seguro de tener todos datos y ejecutar `notifyDataSetChanged()` para llenar tu adapter, en ocasiones no se ven cuando el texto es del mismo color que el background del `ListView`.

Comment: si los colores del background es distinto, y si tengo datos en la tabla, si se pobla la lista se ve que esta llena, pero simplemente no se ven los datos, tengo ese mismo layout con otras listas y se ven los datos

Comment: La lista es "views" ? ya agregaste ADA.notifyDataSetChanged(); ?

Comment: si ya lo agregue, incluso los Edittext al momento de se seleccionar el item se insetan los datos para luego modificarlos, elimniar,

Comment: uso otro metodo para poblar la misma lista y este si se ven los datos siento que algo en el tipo de adaptador que utilizo es el que no despliega

Comment: que método te funciona y que tipo de adapter usas?

Comment: public void cargaPuntoproductor(){SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("SAICoffeeSQL", MODE_PRIVATE, null);Cursor mqry = db.rawQuery("select _id, Latitud, Longitud from TB_previos_productor", null);String[] from = {"_id", "Latitud", "Longitud"};int[] views = { R.id.lblidpunprepro, R.id.lbllatprepro, R.id.lbllonprepro};} esa es la funcion y SimpleCursosAdapter

Comment: Pues yo lo veo todo bien, lo único que no me cuadra es cómo estás seguro que tu `Map` tiene datos, hiciste algún `debug`? tu `AsyncTask` retorna un `String (z)` que no está cumpliendo su función, cuando imprimes esa `z` cuál es su valor?

Comment: me doy cuenta cuando le hago click en el item, me tiene que mostrar los valores en las edittex, si hay cosas que no entiendo tengo un mes viendo android asi que no se aun como funciona del todo

Comment: Por favor, añade a tu pregunta tu `layout` tu fichero `lstpunpreproii.xml`

Comment: amigo no creo que sea el layout ya le cambie de color a las letra, el ancho, en fin ya probe de todo

Comment: ok ya amigo muchas gracias ya me quedo